# A removed question is still visible ..?

Tags: discussion, flags

Once in a while, occasionally, I flag bad answers that should not be visible or flag old questions which are lame or not constructive.

See [my flagging record](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1407478), I think I have demonstrated an understanding of the Stack Overflow concept and so on.

It baffles me that a [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539380/using-graphics-polygons-and-arrays-draw-the-tree-shown-below-you-can-change) I have flagged as "not constructive", and that flag is by the community judged to be "helpful".

[image]

...But that question is still visible and there is no record of deletion.

Why? There is no record of the question being re-opened, so why do I have a positive record of flagging the question, but the question still remains? The flagging concept seems rather useless if there is no consequence for the flagged items.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't flag a comment on the question instead? Your flagging record is not public, by the way.

Comment: @Stijn, OK - this is possible. I have over the years only flagged two or three comments, this could be one of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no not constructive flag for questions or answers.  This is a flag that is only available on comments.

What happened was you flagged a comment on the question as not constructive and it was deleted by a mod.  This marks the flag as helpful and removed the comment.  When you click on the link after the comment was deleted it takes you to the question or answer the comment was attached to instead of the comment as we mere mortals cannot see deleted comments.

Comment: I believe you are right (and I was stupid)