# Why is this self-removed question still visible?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-questions, retracted-flags

I flagged a question and I noticed it was helpful—self removed. But I can still access the question. Why?

This is the question: [phpMyAdmin error: "Cannot connect: invalid settings" in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41993507/3664960)

I noticed the following question on Meta, but this was about a comment, not a question itself according to the comments: [A removed question is still visible ..?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322773/3664960)

Comment: Pretty sure "self-removed" means you retracted the flag...

Comment: My bad, you're right, I removed the flag! But I wanted to change the flag, that's why I ended up here

Comment: Seems to me the next question is: why are flags that get self-removed labelled as "helpful"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel *the next question is: why are flags that get self-removed labelled as "helpful"?* - the question is if this is actually the case. I have some retracted/self-removed flags in my flagging history but don't see "helpful" on any of them. And this is a > 6 yrs old question that was brought back by someone today. But even my retracted flags from that time don't have any "helpful" text on it. It seems to me, after reading the question again, that the OP just got confused by the "self-removed" status and it's not about a real "helpful" mark.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel They aren't, they're labelled as "self-removed". OP just misunderstood what "self-removed" means.

Answer (score 3):

Per comment by [shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9):

> Pretty sure "self-removed" means you retracted the flag.